# jquery datatable pagingType alignment problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

Jquery Datatable

I have tried like this

```
"pageLength": 5,
"pagingType": "full_numbers",
"lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
```

And I am getting result like

FirstPrevious12NextLast

but I want result something like this

[image]

Comment: Please include more details and perhaps a functional example of what you have tried that reproduces the issue here IN the question

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
    "lengthMenu": [
      [10, 25, 50, -1],
      [10, 25, 50, "All"]
    ],
    "pageLength": 1,
    ajax: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bmehler/employees/main/personal",
    "columns": [{
        "data": "id"
      },
      {
        "data": "name"
      },
      {
        "data": "job"
      },
    ]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Job</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Job</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

I think the css file is missing: https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css

Comment: Perhaps take your fiddle and put it in a code snippet IN the question (after you fix the issues within it that it has) `"pageLength": 1,` this is defined twice here and in that fiddle.